# Is it possible to run ARCore on Raspberry pi 3?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, arcore

Is it possible to run ARCore on Raspberry pi 3? It seems it possible to run Android on Raspberry but it's not clear am I able to run ARCore here.

Answer (score 0):

No, Rasberry pi has no camera and no IMU and even if you would add them yourself, it is highly unlikely that Google would provide a calibration for it.

This calibration is needed to understand how to interprete IMU measurements and camera features and translate them into translation and rotation

Comment: It's sad because it would be a good base for a devkit, the same as Pi Zero for aiyprojects.withgoogle.com. I am just curious does Raspberry Pi 3 Model B fit performance requirements of ARCore?